# Replace all spaces at the beginning of each line with a tab

Tags: sed

How can I replace all of the spaces at the beginning of each line with a tab?

I would prefer to use sed for this.

Comment: @StephenRauch Did you mean to have a `^` in there?

Comment: @steeldriver That worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you certain that you wanted to replace _all_ the 0x20 with a 0x09, indiscriminately?  Wouldn't you rather convert groups of the spaces so as to preserve levels of indentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portably.

```
TAB=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/^  */$TAB/" < file.in > file.out
```

Some shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh` and FreeBSD `sh` at least) also support a special form of quotes (`$'...'`) where things like `\t` are expanded.

```
sed $'s/^  */\t/' < file.in > file.out
```

The `fish` shell expands those outside of quotes:

```
sed 's/^  */'\t/ < file.in > file.out
```

Some `sed` implementations like GNU `sed` also recognise `\t`  as meaning TAB by themselves. So with those, this would also work:

```
sed 's/^  */\t/' < file.in > file.out
```

Portably, `awk` does expand `\t` inside its double quotes. And also uses extended regular expressions, so one can use `x+` in place of `xx*`:

```
awk '{sub(/^ +/, "\t"); print}' < file.in > file.out
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU/Linux, there's `sed -r` to enable extended regular expressions:

```
 echo "        lots of spaces    " | sed -r 's:^\s+:\t:'
```

where only the leading spaces are all replaced with a single <kbd>tab</kbd>.